# How to write variables to a file with file_put_contents (PHP)

Tags: php

I am creating a posting system and when the author clicks submit, I need to create a new file (newpost.php) in the same directory. That file will contain the content of the post and the title, author, etc. I have variables for everything like $title, $content, etc. But I also need to add div tag's and things. How can I do that using fwrite or file_put_contents? Right now, I am using file_put_contents. So in the newpost.php file, it will automatically add `echo $content`, etc. But that doesn't work because as soon as I leave the page the variables get destroyed. I need it to be saved in plain text.

Answer (score 2):

Use `serialize` and `file_put_contents` and a few array operations:

```
// Gather data to be saved
$data = array(
    'author' => 'Briedis',
    'content' => 'Content text',
);

// Save to file
file_put_contents('data.txt', serialize($data));


// Read from file
$saved_raw_data = file_get_contents('data.txt');
$saved_data = unserialize($saved_raw_data);

echo "Author:" . $saved_data['author'] . " Contents:" . $saved_data['content'];
```